# Getting specific value from object array for html injection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to get a certain value from a Json file for html injection. The Json can have multiple arrays much more than in this example, but only the first array value of each array has certain value called title. Example json:

```
  var placesdata= {
      "Places": {
        "Berlin": [
          {
            "location": "Center",
            "buildings": "A",
            "title": "Germany"
          },
          {
            "location": "Suburbs",
            "buildings": "B",
          }
        ],
        "Paris": [
          {
            "location": "Center",
            "buildings": "C",
            "title": "France"
          },
          {
            "location": "Suburbs",
            "buildings": "D",
          },
          {
            "location": "Outskirts",
            "buildings": "E",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

I'm inserting all the values to HTML in a function that loops trough all of the arrays in the object. Here the problem is that I don't know how to insert the title value so that the HTML gets it. Tried numerous ways doing it but all failed. I'm trying to insert the title value at toimipistedata[key1][0].title:

```
function CreateAccordionTitles($container) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(placesdata).length; i++) {
        var component =
            '<div class="title">' +
                '<i class="dropdown icon"></i>' +
            placesdata[key1][0].title + 
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="content styleSetSubAccordion">' +
            '<div class="ui two column divided grid ' + Object.keys(placesdata)[i] + '\">' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        if ($container.length) {
            $container.append(component);                        
        }
    }
}
```

(The $container is an id/class for HTML element)
So how can I get the title value from the object arrays so that I can insert it with the HTML?

Tried to make a snippet about how it currently works and what needs to be changed in comments but failed something so it broke:

```js
 var placesdata= {
      "Places": {
        "Berlin": [
          {
            "location": "Center",
            "buildings": "A",
            "title": "Germany"
          },
          {
            "location": "Suburbs",
            "buildings": "B",
          }
        ],
        "Paris": [
          {
            "location": "Center",
            "buildings": "C",
            "title": "France"
          },
          {
            "location": "Suburbs",
            "buildings": "D",
          },
          {
            "location": "Outskirts",
            "buildings": "E",
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    function CreateTitles($container) {
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(placesdata).length; i++) {
            var component =
                '<li>' +
                Object.keys(placesdata)[i] + //this needs to get the title value like this toimipistedata[key1][0].title 
                '<ul class="place ' + Object.keys(placesdata)[i] + '\">' +
                '</ul>' +
                '</li>' 

            if ($container.length) {
                $container.append(component);
                //CreateToimipisteContent(placesdata.Object.keys(placesdataa)[i], "." + Object.keys(placesdata)[i]);  I need this to work
            }

        }
    }
    
        function CreateToimipisteContent(data, elementpos) {

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var dat = data;
            var $txtp = $('<li>' + dat[i].location + '</li>').appendTo(elementpos);
            $txtp.addClass(dat[i].buildings);
        }
    }
    
      CreateTitles($("#Placement"));
        CreateToimipisteContent(placesdata.Poliklinikat, ".Berlin"); // i dont want to use these like this they need to come form the CreateTitles function, these should be removed
        CreateToimipisteContent(placesdata.Tutkimustoimenpiteet, ".Paris"); // i dont want to use these like this they need to come form the CreateTitles function, these should be removed
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="Placement"></ul>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a snippet and lets see what you have made so far. It would be also easier to help you :)

Comment: Well made the snippet thou this does not help in this case. Just added div with an id and function call that sets the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to expand on @ChristianScott's answer a bit, you could loop over `placesdata["Places"]` to get the city, and then use the `find` method to get the title.

So, for completeness:

```js
var placesdata = {
  "Places": {
    "Berlin": [{
        "location": "Center",
        "buildings": "A",
        "title": "Germany"
      },
      {
        "location": "Suburbs",
        "buildings": "B",
      }
    ],
    "Paris": [{
        "location": "Center",
        "buildings": "C",
        "title": "France"
      },
      {
        "location": "Suburbs",
        "buildings": "D",
      },
      {
        "location": "Outskirts",
        "buildings": "E",
      }
    ]
  }
}

let titles = [];  // titles array
for (let city in placesdata["Places"]) {  // for each city
  titles.push(placesdata.Places[city].find(x => x.title).title);  // find & push title
}
console.log(titles);
```

Comment: Using this in the function in console log it gave array of 0 and all the title text came as undefined in the HTML. Used it as titles[i] instead of the original non working placesdata[key1][0].title.

Comment: @metzger I'm confused. Why not just use this to create the titles array first, then loop over that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. But I did set this up in the function before the HTML injection.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Array.prototype.find`, which returns the first element that fulfils the supplied predicate.

I've got no idea what `toimipistedata` is so I'll give you as close an example as I can:

```
var title = placesdata.Places[city].find(x => x.title).title;
```

This works because any element in the `placesdata.Places[city]` array that has the `title` property set will be "truthy", so that object will be returned.

Comment: Sorry about toimipistedata, it's the name used in the original json file I replaced it with placesdata now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple solution using **for in**:

```
var places = placesdata.Places;
for (var place in places) {
    var component =
        '<div class="title">' +
            '<i class="dropdown icon"></i>' +
        places[place][0].title + 
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="content styleSetSubAccordion">' +
        '<div class="ui two column divided grid ' + place + '\">' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>'
    if ($container.length) {
        $container.append(component);                        
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this but sadly it gave no values. Did not produce an error either so on quick testing did not find out why it did not work.